# Getting only file names from the folder in Java8 with Filtering

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8

I want to list out only file names from the folder in Java 8 ending with `.txt` extension.

With this piece of code I got all the files names, and there are a lot with **.txt** extensions:

```
List<Path> fileNames = Files.list(configFilePath)
                .map(Path::getFileName)
                .sorted()
                .collect(toList());
```

But with this code I get an empty:

```
List<Path> fileNames = Files.list(configFilePath)
                filter(file -> file.getFileName().endsWith(".txt"))
                .map(Path::getFileName)
                .sorted()
                .collect(toList());
```

Comment: The `Path` API is really annoying, not only having methods like `getFileName()` returning a `Path` instead of name `String`, but also offering methods like `endsWith(String)` with an entirely different semantic than `String.endsWith(String)`. I don’t know, how often I stumbled across it. The takeaway is, change your code [as suggested by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529624/2711488) or use `file.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")` and remember this as an example of how not to do it when you ever have to design an API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To achieve this, please use the following line of code:

```
Files.list(configFilePath)
    .filter(s -> s.toString().endsWith(".txt"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Your task was to get only file names from the folder which are ending with `.txt`. So the simplest way to achieve this is to use `filter` method which takes as an argument a predicate. Using a predicate it means that is keeps all the elements that satisfy the given condition. Because you have a `List` of `Path` objects we first need to convert those objects to String and check if it ends with `.txt`. Finally we just print the result.

Comment: Your answer would benefit from a small explanation about the difference to the OP’s original code (i.e. what went wrong)…

Comment: I also meant that the OP used `getFileName()` which returns a `Path` having an `endsWith` method not doing the intended thing.